# PDF Driver to print a PDF with page numbers on footer

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-generation

Is there exists a *PDF Driver* to print a PDF with page numbers on footer? I Usually:

- print a PDF with a *PDF Driver*,
- and then I open the printed PDF with another utility to add page numbers on footers.

It is not ok. - I look for a Driver to do it ***in a unique passage***. Do you know it?
Thanks!

---

I can add a detail:
I usually use a Markdown editor as [Typora](https://www.typora.io/), and I want to print a pdf with the above characteristics. So I don't use Adobe Acrobat at all.

Comment: What computer system are you using?

Comment: @EricShain Windows 7

Comment: Can't you just configure the Printer (using CUPS or the printing system dialog) to always  print page numbers onto the page?

Comment: @knb I don't know what is CUPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Black Ice Printer Drivers** can add Header and Footer on the printed document to provide important background information and to make your document look more professional. The Header and Footer feature provides flexibility for better document management by adding User or Document specific information to the printed document such as User name, print date and time.

[Website & Download Link](https://www.blackice.com/Printer%20Drivers/annotation_header_footer.htm)

Hope this helps...

Comment: It is very complete utility. I think that it is not possible to find a free alternative.

Comment: There are many open-source tools(applications) in the market, but drivers are rare. Let me check. I'll update if I find any open-source driver.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for as it isn't in the print driver, but according to [this page](https://itstillworks.com/print-numbers-adobe-acrobat-documents-8318277.html), Adobe Acrobat can do it. From that webpage:

> **Step 1**
>
> Click the "Tools" drop-down menu and select "Pages" to view a list of
>   options. Highlight the "Header & Footer" listing, and select "Add
>   Header & Footer." This process will work for all Adobe Acrobat
>   programs (Standard, Pro and Suite).
>
> **Step 2**
>
> Click once inside one of the six available header and footer
>   sections in which you want to add the page number. Click the "Insert
>   Page Number" button. This action will add the page number that
>   corresponds with the page's position within the PDF file in the
>   selected area. To begin page numbering on a page other than the first
>   page within the file, click the "Page Range Option" link, and select
>   the appropriate page.
>
> Click the "File" menu, and select the "Print" option. Use the "Printer
>   Name" drop-down menu to select a printer from which to print the PDF
>   file. Click the "OK" button to print the Adobe Acrobat document with
>   the page numbers that you added. Save your changes.

There is also a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUu9txmreEs).

Comment: thanks, I knew it, but sorry it must be a pdf driver.